# Why is a 0V DC point at the output of an op amp critical for feedback?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, bias

I am designing an op amp that consists of an active loaded single ended output differential amplifier that is connected to a buffer stage and then an output stage.

When the input signal is connected to the +Vin of the differential amp and the negative input is connected to ground, the circuit needs to be designed so that the output of the op amp's DC point is 0V.

Why does this need to be done so that when the op amp is connected for feedback it works correctly?

Comment: Does it need to really, what's your source? Looks like a load to me, as written on it. Personally never needed any output bias until now at least.

Comment: The output will be a copy of the input, relative to the same ground. Could you clarify what you mean?  Because bias implies that the output is shifted relative to the reference, which clearly is not the case.  I suspect you either misunderstand the concept or miswrote what you mean or choose the wrong word.

Comment: I updated my question hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean.

Comment: A schematic might help us understand what situation you're describing.

Comment: It`s still not clear. High gain opamp? With or without feedback? Which kind of input signal (DC or AC?). Single or dual supply? A circuit diagram can provide much more information than unclear wordings.

Answer (score 1):

"*Why does this need to be done so that when the op amp is connected for feedback it works correctly?*"

Yes - that´s one of the reasons.
In general, for each voltage amplifier it is desired to have zero output for zero input.
That is the reason we use for opamps - in most cases - two supply voltages (split supply). 
In this case, the ouput dc voltage can be designed to be zero (for both inputs grounded, ideal case neglecting offset) with the ability to swing positive and negative.

Otherwise, in case of negative feedback - and if the dc output (Q point) is not zero - we would have a continuos current through the feedback path, even if the input is zero. This would cause an unwanted biasing of the input port. More than that, there also would be a dc current through the connected load (if there is no coupling capacitor).

From this, we can conclude that it is always simpler to realize an ac coupled amplifier chain (consisting of several internal capacitive coupled stages) than a dc coupled amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

Because output circuit must be closed to make current flow possible.

Watch this:

["Introduction to the Op Amp Part" by Darryl Morrel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3RMFpGGcZM) (at youtube.com).